# How to search JPA QueryDSL date with yyyy-MM-dd format?

Tags: java, spring-boot, jpa, spring-data-jpa, querydsl

I am learning SpringBoot JPA's and I am trying to search a database by adding "creationDate=2022-02-02" as a parameter to my uri call. JPA automatically formats the date with a timestamp as "Wed Feb 2 00:00:00 CDT 2022". However, the dates in the databases have timestamps and I believe that since the timestamps do not match, there are no rows returned. How can I search simply by day?

For reference, this is code I inherited. The URI passes in parameters through a QueryDSL predicate. This is then passed into a generic service. I apologize if my understanding of the technologies is wrong.

Note: I can't post the code here as it is company property.

Comment: (reference?) When it's a JPA query, then setting `TemporalType.DATE` (on parameter/+column) should do the job, workaround: `>=` might be sufficient..(?) When it is a native query, then "just truncate"  (hours, minutes, ...) (db platform?)

Comment: @xerx593 I have the TemporalType as Date, but it still doesn't work. I thought the same thing.